# My windows excel icons are same for .xlsx and macro enabled .xlsm files

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, visual-basic

I'm running Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.
The macro enabled .xlsm files, used to have an exclamation mark in their excel icon.
For some time now, all type of excel files have the same simple excel icon.

Anyone knows how it may happened and if i can have my exclamation marked icons back for .xlsm files?

Comment: Have you tried changing the icon for .xlsm files? There shouldn't be anything special about this file type and so you should be able to change the icon to whatever you want. As far as why this may have happened, I'm not sure we can answer this. You may have changed how xlsm files opened at some point in the past and that can change the associate file icons.

Comment: @music2myear You can't change icons to excel files. Only if you create shortcuts of the files. Never changed the default app or installed another software that supports .xlsx files. I'm pretty sure this happened after some update of the Office suite.

Comment: I'm running Excel Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20140 on Windows 10, and my still see the small exclamation mark indicator on xlsm files. I ask if you've changed how xlsm files open, because that can change file icons. You may try a repair install or reinstall of Office and see if that resolves things?